# jQuery - find the index of itself inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```html
<form class="data-table">
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row>
    <div class="col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="has-box">
        <input ...>
        <button> ...</button>
        <div class="modal">...</div>
        <ul class="panel_toolbox">
          <li>
            <a class="close-link">
              <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Inside <`form`>, there are multiple <`div class="row"`>. Except for the first row, all the other rows have <`i class="fa fa-close"`> inside themselves. The purpose of my code is to allow users to remove a row by clicking '`x`' icon. But in order to do that, I first need to know which row the user clicked.

**JavaScript**

```js
$('.close-link').click(function () {
    // if statement makes sure that the user doesn't remove the first row
    if ($('form.data-table').children().length > 2) {
        var $ROW = $(this).closest('.row');
        $ROW.remove();
    }
});
```

The above Javascript code works only for the second row, and from the third row, the remove icon won't work (first row is never to be removed, because it's a title row).

Here's how it looks like.

[image]

How can I edit my jQuery code so that I can detect which row the user clicked, and remove only that row?

++ Additional information
There is an "Add" button at the bottom, and new rows are added when I click the button. So, initially there are only two rows, title row and the input row. If I click add button, a new input row is added, and click is not recognized on the newly-added rows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `closest('div.row')`.
2. Also change the length to **1**

**Example:**

```
$('.close-link').click(function() {
  // if statement makes sure that the user doesn't remove the first row
  if ($('form.data-table').children().length > 1) {
    var $ROW = $(this).closest('div.row');
    $ROW.remove();
  }
});
```

**Update:**(As per question update)

Use the following type `click` event for dynamically added rows also to work.

```js
$("form.data-table").on("click", ".close-link", function() {
  // if statement makes sure that the user doesn't remove the first row
  if ($('form.data-table').children().length > 1) {
    var $ROW = $(this).closest('div.row');
    $ROW.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: still, for some reason click event is not recognized starting from the third row. I put description in Bhusan's answer

Comment: Have you checked with `.closest('div');`?

Comment: yea, I tried that, but it seems the issue is that the click itself is not recognized on the new rows. Can you check the new edit I made on this post?

Comment: your code works! can you please why the upper block of code didn't recognize click, but the latter one did?

Comment: `.click(` this type of click event won't support click event for newly added element. It only supports for the elements which are present at the load time. But `.on("click"` this click event supports for both initially loaded element and dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: You can use `closest()` function to find the parent div and then remove it. Use `index` to find the position of row so that first row will not be removed. Please check below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".close-link", function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest(".row");
        var index = parent.index();
        if (index > 0) {
            parent.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="data-table">
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="has-box">
        <input value="This is value">
        <button>Button</button>
        <div class="modal"></div>
        <ul class="panel_toolbox">
          <li>
            <a class="close-link">Close
              <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the code for getting the row's index works, but for some reason the x mark recognizes only the first x mark. So, each row starting from the second row has its own x mark, and clicking on the other row's x mark doesn't do anything because it's not recognized. How to fix?
++ so 'click' event is not recognized starting from the third row

Comment: @EricKim, I got your problem. I have updated click handler in my post pls use that and let me know if that works. (I made changes to handle dynamically created element)